# Create Multiple Objects in a Loop with different names

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to create a "library" with multiple "shelves", but I can't figure out how to name each shelf differently while creating them using a for loop:

```
function library(initLibraryName, initNumberOfShelves, initNumberOfBooks)
{
    this.name = initLibraryName;
    this.numberOfShelves = initNumberOfShelves;
    this.numberOfBooks = initNumberOfBooks;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfShelves; i++)
    {
       this.shelf = new shelf(i, numberOfBooks/numberOfShelves);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're re-assigning `this.shelf` every iteration. Put them in an array.

Comment: Just use an associative array

Comment: @EdHeal, no such thing in JS.

Comment: @Andy - Yes there is - See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Comment: That's an object. While it's helpful for programmers from other languages where there are such things to make the comparison, there's still no such thing as an associative array in JS.

Comment: @andy - it is the same thing. index on a string.

Comment: You want to carry on talking about associative arrays with other JS developers, don't blame me when you keep being corrected. That nomenclature _does not exist_ when you're talking about JS. I'm not having a go, I'm stating a simple fact. You should use _object_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you creating new instances of shelf, but at first you should declare it

```
// by convention constructor name should start with uppercase letter
function Library(initLibraryName, initNumberOfShelves, initNumberOfBooks) {
    this.name = initLibraryName;
    this.numberOfShelves = initNumberOfShelves;
    this.numberOfBooks = initNumberOfBooks;
    this.shelf = []; // at first you need to define an array
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfShelves; i++) {
        // then push Shelf instances to an array
        this.shelf.push(new Shelf(i, this.numberOfBooks / this.numberOfShelves)); 
    }
}

function Shelf(arg1, arg2) {
    this.prop1 = arg1;
    this.prop2 = arg2;
    this.method = function () {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3052866/user3052866

I realize now that I needed to have an array of shelves in my library class, and that you can't just create multiple objects as part of a function in JS!

Thanks to elclanrs for pointing out the latter!

Comment: This was my first post on stackoverflow, great to be a part of the community!